# Использование dll в Python, typedef (C/C++ -> Python)

Tags: python, c, dll

Допустим, в некотором файле a.dll, написанном на C есть такие строки:

```
typedef void* MyType

MyType foo()
```

Я подключаю эту dll в своём коде на Python. Что я должен указать в

```
lib.foo.restype
```

если я хочу, чтобы это всегда был тип MyType? Т.е., с учётом того, что когда-нибудь внезапно выйдет новая версия этой a.dll, где будет уже

```
typedef void** MyType
```

?

P.S. Конечно, я могу явно написать

```
lib.foo.restype = c_void_p
```

и об обновлении библиотеки узнать вовремя и всё исправить, но есть ли способ сделать это автоматически?

Comment: Делайте юнит тестирование всех функций библиотеки. Если один из тестов не пройдет, лезьте в код.

Comment: @ArchDemon Куда же без него :) И, всё же: неужели нет какого-нибудь способа сказать: `...restype = lib.MyType`?

Comment: Если ABI совместимости, предоставляемой ctypes недостаточно, то используйте cffi в режиме API совместимости